# Refreshing cache in Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, unity-container, factory-pattern

I am new to development in C# so still figuring a few things out.
I am trying to stick to good design principals so as to keep my code maintainable. So doing I am building a Line of Business application using the MVVM and Factory patterns. I am also using Dependency Injection (Unity).

My question is about refreshing the data cache created with Dependency Injection. When I create my View Model the data cache is loaded as follows:

```
_container.RegisterType<IRepo<Relation>, RelationRepo>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

My scenario is that I have a data presented to the users in a GridView. I have a multi user environment with dynamic information so it is possible that from time to time the data in the Cache becomes obsolete. This may result, as could be expected, in an DBConcurrency error from time to time. What I am grappling with is how to handle this in the correct manner. Should I abort the whole process and have the user reload the application thereby recreating the DI or is there an elegant way to refresh the cache and re-present the data after providing necessary information to user. Using the 2n'd option I could perhaps place a refresh button on the screen or a timed event to refresh data so user can see any variations in data.

So basically what I'm asking is how do I keep the Cache in sync with the underlying Data Base in real-time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How this `_container.RegisterType<IRepo<Relation>, RelationRepo>(new TransientLifetimeManager());` is related to cache of any kind? This code registers a **mapping** between an interface and a concrete type with **transient lifetime** which means that the container returns a **new, fresh instance** of the implementation type when asked for an instance of the interface. This doesn't sound like there's caching involved.

Comment: Maybe cache is the wrong term to use. What I mean is that the same instance of data is used for the lifetime of the instance. Which is perfectly logical but in some instances you may need to refresh it.

Comment: According to your mapping, you never get the same instance, since your container uses the **transient** mapping here (= a new instance everytime you ask the container for it). Are you sure it's not the issue with your actual code rather than with the container itself?

Comment: No I am specifically referring to the lifetime of a specific container, where the underlying data changes within the lifespan of said container. I want to try identify these instances to prevent concurrency issues more elegantly. The user may have the GridView open on screen (single container) for a period of time during which data may change.

Comment: There are not enough details on how you implement the cache (what cache?) and how you manage the db connection within the repo (concurrency exceptions suggest two or more threads use the same context, which is awkward considering your container returns transient instances of the repo). I still don't understand how your question is related to the container and I start to believe your repository implementation could be the issue.

Comment: @WiktorZychla thanks for your assistance. I think I am over complicating the question. I accept concurrency issues, that I deal with sufficiently. All I want to achieve (if possible) is to refresh the container holding the transient instance of the repo. I know I could destroy it and re-load it but this is what I wish to avoid.

Comment: This is not how containers work. The container doesn't **hold** any instance, it creates it everytime you ask it for one. Thus, the container doesn't know what happens to the instance just after you get the reference. If same/another thread asks for the type once again, it gets **another, fresh** instance. Either there is still a misunderstanding here or you are not sure how an IoC container works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although its a while ago I thought i'd post the solution to my problem in case someone else is grappling with the concepts as I was.

The issue was that I was not properly disposing my ViewModel when I navigated away from the View (or if there was a DB Error). Therefor when I returned to the View the EF DBContext was still using the local store. i.e not Disposed.

I subsequently implemented the Prism Framework and implemented IRegionMemberLifetime on a base class from which all my ViewModels inherit. This causes the instance of the ViewModel placed in the Region Manager (IRegion) to be removed when it transitions from an activated to deactivated state.

My (pseudo) base class looks like this:

```
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Regions;

public MyBindableBase : BindableBase, IRegionMemberLifetime
{
    public virtual bool KeepAlive => false;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This a very broad question you might prefer to take to the software engineering stackexchange site. There are many approaches for handling this kind of problem.

In any case you are going to have to handle concurrency exceptions. One approach you could take to reduce the chances of their occurrence is by distributing updates to clients via SignalR. Take the approach that a single update will distribute via a SignalR hub to all other clients. Still, the update may be broadcast moments after a concurrent update, and this will require some UI feature to explain that things have changes.